# Intuition behind multiple regression and conditional independence

Tags: regression

Let us assume that we have the following DGP:
$$
Y=X\beta+W\gamma+U
$$
The identifying assumption here is that $E\left(U'\mid W,X\right)=0.$ What does this assumption mean intuitively? Does it mean that no matter what the values of $W$ and $X,$ for each combination of $X$ and $W,$ the average unobsevables are all 0? What is the intuition behind
this?

Comment: It means that, on average, you do not expect high or low values of unobservables when you know the values of observables. Consider examples I have given here https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A67799+ability in the context of "returns to schooling".